# How to enforce image max-width when using bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3, I want an article page to show images of all sizes both responsive and not exceed the article boundaries. Here is the html:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="article">

    <h3 class="title">{{ post.title }}</h3> <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
        {% if post.author %}
            <li class="author">wrote<b>
                    {{ post.author }} </b>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        <li class="pubdate">{{ post.pub_date |date:'Y m d' }}
    </li>


    </ul>


     <div class="img-responsive headimage"> <img src="/media/{{post.headimage}}" />
     </div>

        <div class="open-sans">{{ post.body }}</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.headimage img {

    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This limit the max-width however is hackish the image is not responsive. So I'd like to know how to do it in correct way.

Comment: If you're using angularJS you should use ng-src and not src (just as a side note)

Comment: You are using `.img-responsive` on a non-`<img>` tag, which is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent the image from overflowing the column:

```
.headimage {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.headimage > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```